# Checkbox changestate on mouseover C# ASP.NET JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am creating a checkbox group dynamically and adding them to placeholder control.

c#:

```
 for (j = d; j < b; j++)
                {
                    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
                    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                    cb.Checked = true;
                    cb.ValidationGroup = "seat";
                    cb.ID = "check_" + j.ToString();
                    cb.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "javascript:seatcall(//what is the argument)");
                    cb.Text = j.ToString();
                    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(cb);
                    plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
                }
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function seatcall(//what to pass)
    {

    //how to code? I have tried:document.getElementById(this).checked=false;
  }
</script>
```

I've got:

[image]

I want these checkboxes to be unchecked onmouseover. How to do? Please help me with this code.

Comment: js or C# any code will be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't undo myself from the feeling that you could have done some more research yourself on this one. The main problem with your current tries is that `checked="false"` is far from valid html.You have to completely remove the `checked` attribute.
The best way to accomplish this is by using jQuery. Add a class to you checkboxes, so they get rendered like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="hoverCheckbox"/>
```

Then, using jquery, bind the hover event of the checkboxes:

```
$('.hoverCheckbox').hover(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
});
```